# Java: How to delay an object of a class represented by a shape from 'jumping'?

Tags: java

So the question is: Write a public class method jump() that returns nothing. It should make the wizard(instance of the class represented by a triangle) passed as argument jump up one cell position from its current cell then return to its original cell.

In order to follow the motion of the wizards properly you will need to slow the animation down. To help you do this we have provided a class method delay() in the WizardController class.

e.g. If you want a delay of 100 ms you would insert the following statement at the appropriate point in your code.:

Remember to use delay() at the appropriate point in each of the methods you write to animate the wizards.'

heres my code:

```
public static void jump(Wizard wizard1)
  {
wizard1.upBy(1);
WizardController.delay(10000);
wizard1.downBy(1);
WizardController.delay(10000);
}
```

The code above compiles but when I execute the following to test it.. the 'triangle' shape jumps very quickly without a delay. eventhough I have in my code added delay.How can I delay it properly so 'triangle' waits and then moves one down. Many thanks

```
Wizard w = new Wizard(OUColour.PINK, 1);
Triangle t = w.getPersona();
WizardController.jump(w);
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your post. How do you display the current wizard position? In most GUI frameworks the update of a GUI happens in the main thread. I suspect you shift the wizard up, but the main GUI thread does not get control so does not update the wizards position. Then you wait, move him down, wait again and only then the GUI main thread gets control. So when GUI thread finally gets the control the wizard is already back to the initial position, so you don't see him jumping.

Answer (score 1):

So the jump goes like this. Wizard jumps instantly up, waits out the delay, instantly goes down, waits out the delay. Thats because the program excecutes the code in the sequence written.

In order to solve it and have a fluent jump you have to make changes in the upBy() method, so theres a delay in between increments of x/y value.

Comment: so something like 
wizard1.upBy();?

Comment: i dont know how your upBy() method is defined, but if jumping is something like jump() = y.value + 10, try jump() = y.value + 3; delay(); y.value + 3; delay(); y.value + 2;

Comment: of course you would do it in a loop. Your delay is between the motions, you need delay IN the motion